# On the 404 page, look for an XML file and read it in. If it doesn't exist, display 404 message

Tags: 6

I am wondered if the following is possible: I need to display some XML data on the fly; these should only be created temporarily (ie not nodes or entries in a database and therefore not readable by Google). The URLs for these and the other XML files I import into nodes have the same structure, generated by a third-party system; so I need the page to be generated if the node doesn't exist (so I guess on the 404 page you will be redirected to).

I thought something like this might work. Any pointers?

```
<?php
  $hdr = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //Format of http://example.com/item/######
  $idnr =  substr($hdr, -6);
  $file = simplexml_load_file('http://api.service.com/customerID/item/'.$idnr);

  if (file_exists($file)) {
    // Put my XML fields here.
  } else {
    //Echo 404 message
  }
?>
```

**EDIT** After reading Alfred Armstrong's and develkar's answers I guess what I could think about is something like this: In the `module_menu` callback function: Look for a node with that URL alias. If that doesn't exist, load the XML. If THAT doesn't exist, return a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `hook_menu` you define your page:

```
function MODULE_menu() {
  $items['page-not-found'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'MODULE_page_not_found',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function MODULE_page_not_found() {
  $hdr = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //Format of http://example.com/item/######
  $idnr =  substr($hdr, -6);
  // return an object : http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php
  $file = simplexml_load_file('http://api.service.com/customerID/item/'.$idnr);   

  if($file) {  
    //Put my XML fields here
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_title('Page not found');
    $cust_err = "";
    $cust_err = $cust_err . "The requested page " . current_path() . " could not be found";
    return $cust_err;
  }
}
```

Then go to *admin > settings > error-reporting*, and enter **page-not-found**, the path you defined in hook_menu.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: +1 for how to do it on the drupal side of things (admin settings, menu, etc) but I would look into the rest of the logic.  A quick glance suggests, for example, that `simplexml_load_file()` returns an object, not a path to a file.

Comment: @Jimajamma I didn't check the manual for the return type of the function, just copied it from the OP. I've made the changes that should work. Thank you!

Comment: Using request uri instead of http_referer, this is working so far!

Answer (score 2):

Drupal let you specify custom [403 and 404 error pages](http://drupal.org/node/15366):

```
admin->settings->error-reporting
```

Your custom error page may be PHP, so you can place any logic in it you want, including the one you suggest.

Edit: As already stated by *develkar*, if you do not want this indexed by Google or other search engines, you disallow it in you `robots.txt`.

Comment: How would I make that page not indexable by Google? Wouldn't there still be a node for it to pick up on?

Comment: @ytrewq You could exclude this page from getting indexed by adding it to your `robots.txt` file.

Answer (score 2):

If the URLs follow a pattern, then what you probably want is a custom menu entry and load function, eg:

```
mymodule_menu() {
  $items['somepath/%xml'] = {
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_callback',
    'page arguments => array(1),
     //... rest of menu definition ...
  };
  return $items;
}

mymodule_xml_load($xml_name) {
  // reads the xml and returns an object or returns FALSE
}
```

See http://drupal.org/node/224170

In other words, the Drupal menu system can already do what you want and all you need to do is code for it.

**Edit**: If there's truly no means by which you can distinguish Drupal paths from the XML ones, the  only route I can see is to use [custom_url_rewrite_inbound](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6) to some checking upfront. But you'd have to effectively duplicate Drupal's own menu logic with some differences when it comes to these cases.

Or you could hack core to the same end. Hint: please don't.

Or you could request an exhaustive list of all the XML paths so you could add them as aliases into the Drupal database. In this case you would map each xml path to something like xml/ORIGINALPATH, then in your module use the logic I suggested above.

Comment: Problem is is that the 'somepath' in that would be the XML path... And I have nodes with the same URL pattern. I attempted to use Views/Views XML Backend for this first time around, but for some reason it never gets called and you are instead sent to the 404. Probably because there is no arg[0], it's just www.example.com/######.

Comment: Can you not decide on the URL structure yourself to meet your needs? So all these urls would be of the form eg. www.example.com/xml/someident, the someident part being used to identify the XML file.

Comment: Nope. The structure is determined via a third party system. I have been told it can't be changed.